# CSS dropdown navigation align-right

Tags: html, css, navigation, alignment, dropdown

I've just started learning HTML and CSS, I'm trying to create a dropdown navigation where the edge of the dropdown is aligned on the right hand side with the navigation item for that dropdown. It all works perfectly except the alignment.

I've moved the dropdown list to fall under the 'Home' nav item so that I can see the alignment. I've also seen some pages that suggest to use `right:0` and `left:auto` and I've tried placing that in lots of places, it either does nothing or it moves the whole menu to the right edge of the browser.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/StePeters17/qm4Lkevs/36/

Answer (score 0):

You could set the distance from the right using `right: #px` and you would not need to include `left: auto`. Just replace the # with the number of pixels that you need. You've included a massive amount of code, so I will just tell you what I added to fix the problem and you can run the snippet to see how it works.

If you add `right: 220px` to the `.dropdown-content` class, this will make it align to the right. The text will still be left aligned, but you can change that by adding `text-align: right` to the same class if you also want that text to be right aligned. You want to add it to this class because this is the container for all of the dropdown content.

```css
* {
  /*global settings */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- Navigation bar styling------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*------------- Main Nav Bar-------------- */

.nav-main {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  /*Set the height so that it doesn't auto change and fill screen when dropdown opens*/
  line-height: 36px;
  /* 36 (line height) + 4 (border-bottom) + 2*10 (padding top & bottom) = 60 (height of nav)
}
.nav-main .logo{
 /* insert logo stlying e.g. float left, height etc. */
}

.nav-main ul {
  float: right;
  /*Float the list itself to the right of the header */
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-main ul li {
  float: left;
  /* Float the list items (menu items) left within the list which is floated on the right */
}
.nav-main ul li a {
  right:0;
}

#nav-active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}

.nav-item {
  /* This is the header item links, i.e. the top items which produce dropdowns */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}

/*Next 2 statements will hide and unhide the dropdown on hover of nav item*/
.nav-item:hover ~.dropdown-content{
  max-height:400px;
  -webkit-transition:max-height 0.25s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:max-height 0.25s ease-in;
  transition:max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
.dropdown-content:hover {
  max-height:400px;
}

/*------------- Dropdown styling-------------- */

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  /*This is the height of the header */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-height:0;
  right: 220px;
}

.dropdown-content ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-sub {
  /* This is where we can add things like padding without messing things up */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-sub ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdown-sub ul li {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-sub ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  /* 5px padding top&bottom, 10 on l&r */
}

.dropdown-sub ul li a:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- End of navigation bar styling----------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This is a meta description, this is what often shows up under the search results">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Link to stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheet2.css">
    <!-- Add Roboto font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Add icon library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- This is the top part to all the page docs -->
    <!-- Need to add the header code that appears in all docs -->

    <header>
      <!-- Navigation Bar -->

      <nav class="nav-main">
        <!--This the container for the header -->
        <div class="logo">
          <!-- Insert logo in this container then use css to style, e.g. float left -->
        </div>
        <ul>
          <!-- This is the list of nav headers -->
          <li>
            <!-- This is the actual item for the nav header-->
            <a href="#" class="nav-item" id="nav-active">Home</a>
            <!-- This is the header item link -->
<div class="dropdown-content">
              <!-- Create a couple of divs for the dropdown content... placed at same level as the nav-item itself-->
              <div class="dropdown-sub">
                <ul>
                  <!-- Dropdown list -->
                  <li><a href="#">User Profile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">About</a></li>
          <!-- Can sit on one line if no dropdown-->
          <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">News</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item">Account</a>
            
          </li>
        </ul>

      </nav>

    </header>

    <!-- Since this gets called using php into all page docs, we don't close the <body> and <html> tags here-->
    <!-- Close the <body> and <html> tags in the footer document, which gets called at the end of each page doc -->

    <p>Top Line</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>Blah</p>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do it as an automatic setting, rather than specifying the pixels for each dropdown? 

Like I said, new to HTML and CSS - got this nav layout from a YouTube video (they had it left-aligned though)... If you know a better way of achieving the same result using HTML and CSS as in the jsfiddle then please let me know!

Comment: Not really. Most dropdown navbars are separate navs (or in your case a separate div) that are hidden by default until a hover or mouseover event causes them to be visible, so it's not actually part of the original navbar. You could try a framework like Bootstrap or Semantic UI, but as a beginner, you might be in over your head when it comes to customizing their components.